# Scipy Weibull Min Fit bad without forced location

Tags: python, scipy, weibull

I'm currently trying to fit a dataset that I have using the scipy.stats weibull_min.fit function.  When I fit the dataset outright, I get the following parameters:

```
(0.10875037748866037, 1.0362199999999999e-05, 1.0709034507962369)
```

This ends up being a very bad fit to the data.  However, when I force the location (second parameter) to be the min value of the dataset, I get a much better fit:

```
(1.2295613161155923, 1.03622e-05, 5.8737285599676099e-06)
```

As you can see, the value of my forced location and the auto fit location are very, very close.  Is there any reason that fitting the data without forcing the location yields a much worse result?

EDIT:
Here is the code that I am using:

```
import scipy.stats as st

file = open('datafile.csv', 'r')
lines = file.readlines()

data = []
for ii in range(len(lines)):
    data.append(float(lines[ii]))

distr = getattr(st, "weibull_min")

params = distr.fit(data)
# params = distr.fit(data, floc=min(data))
```

Comment: Can you share your data? Or something similar to your data. Makes it easier to reproduce.

Comment: Sharing some code you use would help too. The `weibull_min.fit` function takes named parameters which you probably refer to but it is hard to say without the actual code.